# Extrude along Local axis

Tags: modeling

I made an inset and want to extrude it along its local axis I'm trying to extrude the tip of this kettle,I have turned on from the transformation orientation local axis.I tried on the Y and Z, and both go incorrect direction. I'm trying to get it along the axis as shown in the example.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: normally, if you just press "E", the face should be extruded in the direction that it is facing. Is this not the case in your project? If not, please provide your .blend file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.

Comment: Here is the Blender file:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=zzanl4YE" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/zzanl4YE/)

Comment: The orientation show in the last screenshot isn't local axis for that face as it doesn't have any similar orientation (so Normal won't work too). As that drawn line is parallel to faces in the bottom of the tip you can create new transform orientation with that face selected, deselect it and extrude (or align viewport with those faces)

Comment: actually the axis you're talking about is neither aligned to global nor to local, so what you could do is select a face that is aligned or perpendicular to the good direction, then align the view with some shift 1 (or 3 or 7), then Transformation Orientation > View, and use the widget to move the extrusion

Comment: I understood up to the:  Transformation Orientation > View, can you please screenshot this?

Thank you.

Comment: https://zupimages.net/up/20/23/jnht.jpg

Comment: if I understand correctly you want to extrude along the teapot spout axis?

Comment: Maybe this is what was implied for me to do or maybe not. But I ended extruding the face then using the <kbd>g</kbd> to drag it inwards and giving it a bit of a rotation.

https://ibb.co/1Lct5FP

Comment: I think your question was not clear, if I understand it correctly ( extrude along the teapot spout axis) I gave you an answer, another method would be to glide the face along the spout direction (GG), extend it outwards with alt, then recreate an edge loop where it is supposed to be in the middle of the spout, with GG then E to align the new edge loop on the right inclination

Comment: is there a specific terminology which you specified, so I can search it on a video tutorial?